# Log Analytics workspace - Alerts to list

Tags: azure, powershell

Alerts can be listed like that with az cli like that

```
$activities = az monitor activity-log list -g $ResourceGroup
```

which produces in PowerShell a string but is a list of JSON's.

Any one knows why $activities is not a PSCustomObject which I could use ?

Comment: Because `az` is an executable and executables return strings, not objects :) Is `$objects = $activities |ConvertFrom-Json` (or `$objects = $activities |% {$_ |ConvertFrom-Json}`) not working?

Comment: We should use ConverFrom-Json then you can list it.

Comment: you both are right, thought the solutin below is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with @Mathias R. Jessen that

> `az` is an executable and executables return strings, not objects

```
$activities = az monitor activity-log list -g "Resourcegroup"
$res=$activities | ConvertFrom-Json                              
$res
```

Output:

[image]

Now you can use Dot Operator as below:

[image]